# setInterval in for loop

Tags: javascript

Here's what I'm attempting to do: add 1 new class name every 3 seconds and then stop after 5 have been added.  When I run this code, it keeps adding classes indefinitely! It also adds 3 classes all at 1 time.

```
var linesOfText = ['Testing Second Part', 'Testing Third Part', 'Testing Fourth Part', 'Testing Fifth Part'];
var j = 1;
var total = 5;
for (var i = linesOfText.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

   var myVar = setInterval(function(){
      $('.vertical-effectOFF').addClass('vertical-effect-' + j);
      j++;
      if (j === total) {
        console.log('stop!');
        clearInterval(myVar);
      }
   }, 3000);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try taking out the for loop and changing `j = 5` to `j = 0`:

```
var linesOfText = ['Testing Second Part', 'Testing Third Part', 'Testing Fourth Part', 'Testing Fifth Part'];
var j = 0;
var total = 5;
var myVar = setInterval(function(){
   $('.vertical-effectOFF').addClass('vertical-effect-' + j);
   j++;
   if (j === total) {
     console.log('stop!');
     clearInterval(myVar);
   }
}, 3000);
```

This will add a class every 3 seconds until 5 classes are added.

Comment: Is there a good way to add a setTimeout after the .addClass() line?  I need to wait a few seconds, do something and then go to the j++ line.

Comment: @Tom check out this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/what-do-i-do-if-i-want-a-javascript-version-of-sleep

Comment: I have an extension of this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30873346/settimeout-within-setinterval-not-firing-as-expected

Answer (score 0):

Using a for loop for this is not the best approach. It is not functioning as expected because it set 5 intervals *immediately* to **all** execute after 3 seconds. Just set the interval to call a named function and terminate it when `j === total`

```
var j = 1;
var total = 5;

var myVar = setInterval(intervalAddClass, 3000);

function intervalAddClass() {
    $('.vertical-effectOFF').addClass('vertical-effect-' + j);
    j++;
    if (j === total) {
        console.log('stop!');
        clearInterval(myVar);
    } 
}
```

Also, there is no need for `linesOfText` as you are not using it in your code.