# setTimeout() within setInterval not firing as expected

Tags: javascript

I have my code below.  What I need to do is run some code every 2 seconds which works.  This is the setInterval part of the code.

I also need to run some other code every n*2+1 seconds.  This is the part that's not working.  It's in the setTimeout function.  See this part (j * 2000 + 1000).

```
var linesOfText = ['Testing First Part', 'Testing Second Part', 'Testing Third Part', 'Testing Fourth Part', 'Testing Fifth Part'];
var j = 1;
var total = linesOfText.length;
var myVar = setInterval(function(){
 var d = new Date();
 var n = d.getSeconds();
 console.log('top - ' + n);
   $('.vertical-effectOFF').addClass('vertical-effect-' + j);
   setTimeout(function(){
       var d = new Date();
       var n = d.getSeconds();
       console.log('middle - ' + n);
       console.log(j * 2000 + 1000);
   }, j * 2000 + 1000);


   j++;
   if (j === total) {
     console.log('reset');
     j = 1;
   }
}, 2000);
```

Comment: `This is the part that's not working.` what's not working? Is it not running your code? Is it running at the wrong time? Is it giving you error messages?

Comment: ^ and add a JSFiddle, this will usually get quicker answers

Comment: @MattBurland It's not running at the right time.  The setInterval function should run at 2 sec, 4 sec, 6 sec, etc.  The setTimeout should run at 3 sec, 5 sec, 7 sec, 9 sec, 11 sec, etc.  I'd provide a jsfiddle but I don't want to kill you with alerts (and console.log are not shown)

Comment: I think everybody who might be able to answer your question is more than capable of opening the console when looking at a jsfiddle. So when are they running it they aren't running at the right time? What makes you think they aren't running at the right time?

Comment: @MattBurland By looking at the console. The console.log('middle - ' + n);
is returning middle - 8, middle - 8, middle 12, middle 12.  It should be middle 8, middle 10, middle 12, middle 14, etc.

Comment: You can also use "Code Snippet" in the editor to put the code as a runnable snippet.

Answer (score 0):

If someone else has a similar problem, this is how I solved it.

```
var linesOfText = ['Testing First Part', 'Testing Second Part', 'Testing Third Part', 'Testing Fourth Part', 'Testing Fifth Part'];
var j = 1;
var total = linesOfText.length;
var myVar = setInterval(function(){
 var d = new Date();
 var n = d.getSeconds();
 console.log('top - ' + n);
   $('.vertical-effectOFF').addClass('vertical-effect-' + j);

   j++;
   if (j === total) {
     console.log('reset');
     j = 1;
   }
}, 2000);




setTimeout(function(){
 var myVar = setInterval(function(){
  var d = new Date();
  var n = d.getSeconds();
  console.log('middle - ' + n + ' - ' + j);

 }, 2000);
}, 1000);
```